# How to echo multiple where clauses in a CI query on screen

Tags: codeigniter

I'm attempting to get the results of a database table and echo the query results.
Here is my code:

```
$queryDB = $this->db->select('*')
                ->from('dr_template_relational')
                ->where('value_id', $categoryDetails['value_id'])
                ->where('subcategory_id', $categoryDetails['subcategory_id'])
                ->get();
echo "<br>";
echo "here is queryDB";
echo($queryDB);
echo "that was it";
```

`$queryDB` doesn't echo even so I'm sure the data is there.  I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.  I'm not getting an error, but also don't get any output with `echo($queryDB);`  on screen it displays:

```
here is queryDBthat was it
```

Comment: what do you want to see? the last generated query? or the query result?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, the query result of $queryDB @Vickel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your approach is just echoing out the instance of the query.

In order to see the query results, you need to create them. There are several CI functions like `result()` and `row()`

at the end it could look like this:

```
foreach ($queryDB ->result() as $row){
        echo $row->value_id;
        echo $row->subcategory_id;
}
```

see [Generating Query Results](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

hint: in order to see the generated query you could use

```
echo $this->$db->last_query();
```